# Python 3 - How to import all classes located in files of sub-directory at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have folder structure like this:

```
/
main.py
firstsetofclasses/
----__init__.py
----class1.py
----class2.py
----class3.py
secondsetofclasses/
----__init__.py
----class4.py
```

What I want to do is, inside main.py which is at the root folder:

```
import firstsetofclasses
import secondsetofclasses

MyFirstObject = class4()
MyFirstOject.do_some_thing()
```

And inside class4.py which is inside secondsetofclasses folder:

```
import firstsetofclasses

MySecondObject = class1()
MySecondObject.do_another_thing()
```

My purpose is make the structure more clear and whenever new class created inside the folder automatically imported to other necessary files. 
Note that i want to keep class names and file names same.

How can I establish this?

Comment: That's not the recommended naming scheme. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names

Comment: Those names are symbolic unless it is about naming the file with class name?

Comment: Right. They can't be the same if you follow the style guide, since it specifies different style names for classes and modules.